# Number of triangles possible in android lock patterns?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I recently starting using the patternlock on my android phone and i play around with it a lot, just drawing lines until im locked out for 30 secs.

I thought i'd make it into a pointless game of sorts. For the thing i have in mind i'd want to know how many triangles you can create with the pattern.

In an answer to question in the link below, it's demonstrated how to compute the amount of different patterns you can draw.

http://www.quora.com/How-many-combinations-of-locking-pattern-are-possible-for-a-Samsung-3*3-locking-grid

[Example image of possible triangles in patterns](http://s10.postimg.org/v7v1enxy1/samsungtriangles.png)

The question is then how would one go about calculating this? (I think defining all the triangles **except** the two colored ones in the image above as legal unique triangles. Drawing the pattern 'forwards' or 'backwards' obviously has no effect on the triangle. All i can think of is actually brute-painting all of them and do some shape finding algorithm. Is there a clever way to model this?

Comment: No duplicates, I think, but perhaps relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=android+pattern